# How to change Formview mode with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, formview

I have a `formview` on my web page and I want to change `formview mode`. But I want to change this with `javascript`.

Is this possible?
i have a `repeater` which has buttons. And i have a button outside of repeater. when i click the button where is outside, it shows formview in popup. this formview has to be insert mode. And when i click the button where is on repeater, it shows `formview` in `popup`. this `formview` has to be edit mode. But i cant do this c#. may be if i do this with `javascript`, it will works

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="toolkitmanager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkFake" />
        <asp:ImageButton  ID="img1" runat="server"  PostBackUrl="javascript:$find('popUpBehavior').show();"/>
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" ID="popUpCompanyEmployee"
            runat="server" PopupControlID="panel1"
            TargetControlID="lnkFake" BehaviorID="popUpBehavior" CancelControlID="btnKapat">
            </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:FormView ID="fv1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="ID" DefaultMode="Insert">
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblProductName" runat="server" Text="ProductName"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtProductName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblQuantity" runat="server" Text="Quantity"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUnitPrice" runat="server" Text="UnitPrice"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnitPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UnitPrice") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblProductName" runat="server" Text="ProductName"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtProductName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblQuantity" runat="server" Text="Quantity"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUnitPrice" runat="server" Text="UnitPrice"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnitPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UnitPrice") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:FormView>

                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="btnKapat"/>
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <asp:Button  ID="btnkapat" runat="server" Text="kapat"/>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rpr1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblProductName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ProductName") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Quantity") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblUnitPrice" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UnitPrice") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgPopup" runat="server" PostBackUrl="javascript:$find('popUpCBehavior').show();" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:NET2ConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ProductsRA]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: where is the relevant code related to it ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, changing the mode of a `FormView` reflects what controls (html) are rendered to the page.

So it could not happen purely on client-side. You could use an update panel , so only an `asyn post back`is done and only the form view html is refreshed.

Have a look for reference [Formview](http://forums.asp.net/t/1131001.aspx?Change%20mode%20of%20FormView%20client%20side%20with%20javascript)

Documentation for reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227992(v=vs.140).aspx)

Hope it clears your doubt a bit

Comment: thanks for your interest. i will check references which you send :)

Comment: sure, do not forget to mark the post if it helped you

Comment: sorry but it doesn't help

Comment: What exactly is not working? You need to specify more on your requirement

Comment: i have a repeater which has buttons. And i have a button outside of repeater. when i click the button where is outside, it shows formview in popup. this formview has to be insert mode. Ande when i click the button where in on repeater, it shows formview in popup. this formview has to be edit mode. But i cant do this c#. may be if i do this with javascript, it will works.

Comment: U should have mentioned all these things in your question. Please edit your question and
`1. mention what you have`.  `2. What did you tried till now`. `3. Where you are facing issue`. `4. what exactly you want output`